# How to get the user name in sql when a query is run against a Reference table in MemSQL?

Tags: singlestore

When I execute below query on a MemSQL  sharded table, it runs fine and gives me the user who executed the query.

```
INSERT INTO `schema_Version` (`installed_rank`,`version`,`description`,`type`,`script`,`checksum`,`installed_by`,`execution_time`,`success`) VALUES (4, '2', 'First', 'SQL', 'V1__First.sql', 814278929, USER() ,147470, 1)
```

But if I run the same query against a MemSQL Reference table, I get a warning as below:

```
Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): The query cannot be executed. MemSQL code generation has failed: g++ compilation error.
          <---
```

Looks like the USER() is not supported in Reference table only. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your running an older version of MemSQL.   I tried the query above on MemSQL 5 and it worked. I recommend upgrading to the latest version of MemSQL, its painless (http://docs.memsql.com/docs/upgrading-memsql).